# How to open a zip file in PyCharm?

Tags: macos

I am trying to download some starter code from a neural network that can learn to recognize hand written digits. Whenever I go to GitHub to download the zip file and I try to open it in on PyCharm I get this error down below. Any suggestions on how I can fix this? I am on a Mac by the way.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic75O.png)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk&t=118s

thanks

Comment: I think this could be resolved by a quick search on your favourite browser but, why you wanna open a zip with PyCharm? Can you just unzip it and open the project contained inside?

Answer (score 1):

You can unzip the file to a folder and then open file as PyCharm project.
You can also instead of downloading a zip just copy a clone url from GitHub, go to PyCharm -> New project -> from source control -> git -> paste clone url into correct place.